# How to handle many images in an Android app

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I am writing an app that has a lot of images (about 200) which are different items that you can select and order. So far I have been using Glide to load the images from file. To support different resolutions, I made a image of the item with my smartphone and converted them into the 5 different Android resolutions in the folders drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi.

The problem is that the original image has as size of 4,2 MB and all 5 images together just for one item for the different resolutions have a size of 18 MB (0,7 MB, 1,5 MB, 2,5 MB, 5,6 MB and 7,8 MB). If I now do this for 200 images, I will have to store 3,6 GB of images within the app. Thus, the size of the app would be extremely big.

So I would like to know what is a good way of dealing with so many images in an app? Is there a way to include multiple images for different resolutions while still having an app whose size is not enormous?

Comment: "the original image has as size of 4,2 MB" -- that seems rather large. What is the resolution of this image?

Comment: @CommonsWare: Thanks for your comment. Actually I can't find the original image any more, but only the version in the folders drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi. For example, the image in drawable-xxhdpi has a resolution of 4032*3024 and a size of 7,8 MB). I took it with my smartphone camera and generally the images there have a resolution of 4032*3024. So even when I reduce the size of the original image, I will have huge abounts of image data and my question is how to cope with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following steps:-

1. First of all, compress all of your 200 images. I will suggest you to use [this website](https://tinypng.com/) or any other.
2. After that add all the images to your drawables.
3. Convert all of your images to **'webp'** using **Android Studio**.

[1st Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEOfr.jpg)

Set the quality percentage according to your desire

[2nd Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mfYk.png)

See the difference of image sizes

[3rd Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mENnA.png)

In this way, quality will not be much compromised & large size problem will be solved.

-> Drawable Folder Position
[image]

```
loadGlide(R.drawable.testing, imageView)
```

Call this function from everywhere

#### Kotlin

```
private fun loadGlide(resId: Int, imageView: ImageView) {
    Glide.with(context).load(resId).with(imageView)
}
```

#### Java

```
public static void loadGlide(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    Glide.with(getContext()).load(resId).with(imageView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for your answer. How strong can I reduce the size of the images without having a bad image quality using your approach? If I can reduce it by 50 %, I'll still have images of the size of around 1,8 GB which is still too much.

Comment: According to my experience, you might be able to reduce upto 70-80%. Additionally, you can resize the images as well. Like, if in your application you are displaying image about 400*350 dp,,, you can scale them update such resolutions. The standard, I think you can go for 720*480 px. It will also save your memory a lot. For resizing, you can use this [link](https://www.simpleimageresizer.com/)

Comment: Hi Ahmend, I have a follow up question to your suggested approach. Is it possible to just store one single image instead of having one image for each folders drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi? Thus, I could just store one good image (using your approach) and the app should always use this, independant of hdpi, mdpi, xhpi etc.?

Comment: Yes, you can save image in just 'drawable', it will work for all. And I will suggest you to use Glide library for loading images, So that there will be no chance of any lags or ANR's as images will be loaded on background thread.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed for your answer. In which folder do I have to save the one image, that is then used for all densities? Normally I have the folders drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi. Which name should the drawable folder have? I also tried what was suggested by CommonsWare and use the folder name `res/drawable-anydpi/` but this did not work well (see answer below)

Comment: I have added an image in my answer, you can simple copy all your images to 'drawable' folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahmed for your help. It helped. I really appreciate it. I accepted your answer

Comment: @Ahmed: It's me again. You worte that " I will suggest you to use Glide library for loading images". I once used glide but I did not see any advantages. On the contrary, it increases the code length. So why shall I use it?  And what do I have to write instead of `binding.imageView.setImageResource(resId);` in Gllide

Comment: Actually, glide load images on background thread. As you are going to use multiple images with different sizes, small smart phones or those who have 2GB ram may produces ANR.. Whenever there's a large amount data to be drawn on UI, we try to use the best practice.

Comment: You can create a function, and call that function from everywhere. In this way, your code duplication will be saved.. I updated the answer. Plz have a look

Comment: @Ahmed. Thanks a lot for your answer and effort. I really appreicate it. Unforunately, I don't use Kotlin but Java, so I can't use your code. Further, If I want to call the function from anythere, I think it has to be a static method such that I can call it from every other class

Comment: Yes, exactly.. You are welcome

Comment: Do you know how your suggested function looks in Java?

Comment: Updated my answer, added in java too

Comment: Thanks for the update Ahmed. Unfortunately it does not work. When I use the code `Glide.with(context).load(resId).with(binding.imageView);`, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'context'". When I use `Glide.with(getContext()).load(resId).with(binding.imageView);` I get the error message "Cannot resolve method 'with' in 'RequestBuilder'"

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Ahmed. Any comment to my last comment. I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Ahmed. Any comment to my last comment. I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you

Comment: No dear, that's all

Comment: But why do I get the errors when using your suggested Java code? Don't you have any idea?

Comment: What sort of errors.. kindly share

Comment: I already shared them in one of my previous comments. When I use the code Glide.with(context).load(resId).with(binding.imageView);, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol 'context'". When I use Glide.with(getContext()).load(resId).with(binding.imageView); I get the error message "Cannot resolve method 'with' in 'RequestBuilder'"

Comment: Any comments to my last comment about the error messages that I get when using your suggested code?

Comment: can you show me the code.. Please attach Screenshot

Comment: The code is too long. It is the code that I shared in my comments. It is executed within a`onCreateView` method of a fragement.

Comment: Can you share your code in this link.. https://onecompiler.com/java/3ysrbh2ky

Comment: The relevant part is just `int resId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier( "foto", "drawable",  getContext().getPackageName());
Glide.with(context).load(resId).with(binding.imageView);`

Comment: It's still unable to understand, this piece of code looks fine for glide.

Comment: When I use your suggested code, I get the error message "Cannot resolve method 'with' in 'RequestBuilder'". So the `with` is marked in red and causes the error. I can't compile the code because of this error. Maybe it's worth mentioning, that I import `import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;` in the class. The class itself is a Fragment and the erroneous code is executed in the `onCreateView` of the Fragment. In the `build.gradle` file I import glide by using `implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'`. Can you make something out of it?

Comment: You need to add this one too in gradle. 
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'

Comment: See this link for working procedure. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/loading-image-using-glide-in-android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250631/discussion-between-vanessaf-and-sohaib-ahmed).

Answer (score -1):

> I took it with my smartphone camera and generally the images there have a resolution of 4032*3024

Have just one copy of the image, in `res/drawable-anydpi/` to use it for any density.

The density-specific drawable system is designed for much smaller images than the full screen (icons, logos, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Commons for your answer. Unforuantely when using your suggested approach, the image looks extremely bad. The displayed resolution is ridiciously small. I use the following code to display it `int resId = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier( "vienna_test", "drawable",  getContext().getPackageName());
        binding.imageView.setBackgroundResource(resId);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Commons. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.

Comment: @VanessaF: `setBackgroundResource()` may not be a good choice. Perhaps you should use an `ImageView` and display the image there [using `setImageResource()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView?hl=en#setImageResource(int)).

Comment: Thanks Commons for your comment. I tried your suggested approach. Unforuantely, it does not change anything. The image looks quite bad. You mentioned "The density-specific drawable system is designed for much smaller images than the full screen (icons, logos, etc.)." If this is true, what is then the common approach for displaying images in Android?

Comment: @VanessaF: Approximately 0% of apps have image resources where the images have resolutions anywhere near what you want to use. Apps that show such high-resolution images are getting them from places other than resources, such as existing on-device content (e.g., photos) or from the Internet (e.g., Web service).

Comment: Thanks Commons for your comment. Is it possible to just upload the same image file to all different Android resource folders drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi? This way I could just use one image and reduce its quality. The problem is that if I use tools for creating the different images for the different resolutions (like https://appicon.co/#image-sets) they automatically sclae the images up and thus increase its size again, altough there is no gain in quality

Comment: @VanessaF: That would go against what you ask for in the question.

Comment: The idea behind that is to reduce one image in quality and thus in size from 4,2 MB to about 0,5 MB. Now I could just copy and paste this image to all Android drwable folders drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi directly, resulting in 2,5 MB per image which would result in a total size of 0,5GB for all images (compared to the 3,6 GB when not reducing the quality). The big problem is, that when using appicon.co/#image-sets for generating the different images for the different resolutions, the images are increased again in size

Comment: Thanks Common for your comment. Any comments to my last comment? I'll highly appreciate every further comment from you.